# Is the brand Chef's Quality pas yisroel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, pat-yisrael

Are the products under the brand, Chef’s Quality, pas yisroel? All of them, some of them, or none of them? If not all of them are then specifically are their bread crumbs and tortillas pas yisroel?

Comment: Answers here may be outdated, O Future Reader.

Comment: Welcome back, Dude.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reaching out to the kosher certifying company.

Some of them.

The frozen bread products:
As of last I checked (December 2017) unless it says they are, they are not. They are not on the KVH pas yisroel list http://kvhkosher.org/certified-pas-yisroel-list-5778/. The ones certified by the chof-k state next to the hechsher that they are pas yisroel.

The bread crumbs and tortillas where not last I checked.